# What would cause normal files to be hidden from the Finder but not the terminal?

Tags: macos, finder, permission

I exported a set of photos from my wife's computer to mine over a WiFi share. I opened the directory in Finder and it said that there were 0 files. I know I've seen the Finder lag before on recognizing files in the folder, but this wasn't one of those cases.

I went into the terminal and I could see all the files were there and these were not "UNIX hidden" filenames (i.e. prefixed with a period). However, I did notice that they had extended attributes for com.apple.FinderInfo and com.apple.quarantine. I removed both of these attributes figuring that might be it and now the files were simply `-rw-------` permissioned. I even chmod'd them to allow group/other permissions, however, they STILL didn't appear in the Finder. If I attempted to use the command `open IMG_0123.JPG` from the terminal (both before and after every action I tried), they would happily appear in the Preview application. I was finally able to see them after I copied them to a FAT32 partition and then copied them back.

FWIW, the files were copied between Mavericks machines.

So my question is why would these files not appear in the Finder?

Comment: Can you replicate the issue? if yes, do they have the _hidden_ attribute as shown in Matthieu Riegler's answer?  If yes, you can unhide them using the following command from the command prompt set to the containing directory: `setfile -a v *.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On BSD you have a file flag that allows you to hide the file.

`$ chflags hidden path/to/file` to hide a file.

You can see the flag with ls -lO

```
$ ls -Ol foo.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 harry staff - 0 17 Jun 15:57 foo.txt
$ chflags hidden foo.txt
$ ls -Ol foo.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 harry staff hidden 0 17 Jun 15:57 foo.txt
```